# Splitting a file into multiple file based on some pattern in python

Tags: python, file

the text file is like:

```
shfhsgfkshkjg
gkjsfkgkjfgkfg
model        1
lkgjhllghfjgh
kjfgkjjfghg
endmodel
model        2
jfhkjhcgbkcjg
xhbgkxfkgh
endmodel
```

i want between each model and endmodel ,what is the text should be in the new file.and file name should be like model1,model2....model may be 100 or more.and the space between model and number is 8 space exactlyplease help me.

Comment: Smells a little like homework, especially since you already [tried to get an answer about 3 days ago](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/958055-splitting-file-into-multiple-file-based-some-pattern). Perhaps you should try [googling your problem](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tutor/86641/). [Many results are found[(http://www.python-it.org/forum/index.php?topic=5675.0)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Nice find. It looks like he got all the information needed to write an answer, except for someone writing all of the code for him… And now he has that too.

Answer (score 3):

```
def writeFiles(infilepath):
    outfile = None
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('model') and outfile is None:
                outfile = open(line, 'w')
                continue
            elif line == 'endmodel':
                outfile.close()
                outfile = None
                continue
            elif outfile is not None:
                outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for getting my back, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
fileName = "text.txt"

inputfile = open(fileName, 'r').readlines()

files = {}
storeContent = False
content = ""
for line in inputfile:
   if "endmodel" in line.strip() and storeContent:
      files [storeContent] = content
      storeContent = False
   elif "model" in line:
      storeContent = line.replace(" ", "").strip()
   elif storeContent:
      if not content:
         content += line
      else:
         content += "\n" + line
   else:
      pass # ignore other content

for name, content in files.items():
   f = open(name + ".txt", "w")
   f.write(content)
   f.close
```

Comment: I think this answer is more accurate ...

Comment: i edited it..tell me one thing if the spcae between model and the number is exact 8 space then what should i do to exactly to implement it

Comment: This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below function to do this. This is based on below assumptions:
1. There are some junk characters before first model appears
2. after every endmodel there is model.
```

`def file_read():
        path = 'D:\\'
        file = open(os.path.join(path,'dummy.txt'),'w')
        k = open('test.txt', 'r')
        count = 0
        for line in k.readlines():
            if line.startswith('endmodel'):
                continue
            if line.startswith('model'):
                count += 1
                file = open (os.path.join(path,'model' + str(count) + '.txt'),'w')
                continue
            file.write(line)`

Let me know if that does not works for you.

Comment: i want to say lot of thnx..it worked...
can u explain why did u use os.path.join???
thnx again.

Comment: i edited it..tell me one thing if the spcae between model and the number is exact 8 space then what should i do to exactly to implement it.

Comment: I used os.path.join because it is just a good convention and takes care of the wrong slashes per OS.

 Also, i do not think it would be any issue. I just tried and it worked fine for me.
May i ask for an upvote in case this answer solves your problem. Thanks.